# Getting button value in backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I want to get the value saved in a button in backbone view, but can't seem to get it to work.

I have a couple of buttons in the html template :

```
<button class='remove-group-button' value='1'>X</button></div>
<button class='remove-group-button' value='2'>X</button></div>
```

And in the view I have an event on the button click and i'm trying to get the value from the button

```
    events: {
        "click .remove-group-button":          "groupRemoved"
    },

    groupRemoved: function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("groupRemoved");
        console.log(e);
        console.log($(this).attr("value")); // a feeble attempt which failed miserably
    },
```

What would be the correct way to get the value from the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` in a Backbone event handler is rigged to be set to the `View`. Fortunately, what you want is contained in the event object which is passed to the function.

So you can do this:

`$(e.currentTarget).attr('value')`

Comment: Thanks! Tried to use the $, but apparently didn't use it properly. This works! Thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you?

```
e.target.attr('value')
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLButtonElement> has no method 'attr'